# Doc file issues with UIDocumentPickerController in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud, uidocumentpickervc

I am using below code for showing the document picker.When i show the picker i use below code

```
let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeText), String(kUTTypePDF), String(kUTTypePNG), String(kUTTypeJPEG), String(kUTTypePlainText), String(kUTTypeImage)], in: .import)
```

Above code shows me the all files in my iCloud but it does not let me select the doc,docx files.These files appear as disabled.

But when i addd `"public.data"` as element in `UIDocumentPickerViewController` constructor then it is allowing me select doc,docx file & file does not appear as disabled.

Please tell me why this is happening ?

Answer (score 8):

Just posting answer to help other user for this.

To choose `.docx` file via document picker you need to use `org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document` type.

```
let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["com.microsoft.word.doc", "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document"], in: .import)
```

**For iOS 14.0+**

```
let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.appleArchive])
```

Thanks for the update @sadegh bitarafan

Comment: It's deprecated on iOS 14. Instead use this:
```swift
UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.appleArchive])
```

Comment: The version for iOS 14.0+ doesn't work. Got compiling error in Xcode 14.

Answer (score 6):

To be able to select doc and docx, you have to use public.data.

> com.microsoft.word.doc conforms to public.data

kUTTypePlainText only allows files of .txt type

To allow only doc give "`com.microsoft.word.doc`"

```
let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [com.microsoft.word.doc], in: .import)
```

For more information: [System-Declared Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1)

Comment: What if i don't want allow user to select the ppt & xls files only doc & docx file

Answer (score 1):

More help for a bunch of types:

```
let types = [kUTTypePDF, kUTTypeText, kUTTypeRTF, kUTTypeSpreadsheet, kUTTypePNG, kUTTypeJPEG, kUTTypeGIF, "com.microsoft.word.doc" as CFString, "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document" as CFString]
```